# Add class to td with colspan=2

Tags: html, addclass, html-table

I want to add a Class to every td which has `colspan=2`:

```
<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>zuppa di zucchini</td>
            <td>€ 6,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">huisgemaakte soep van courgette met munt</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>insalata caprese</td>
            <td>€ 6,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">frisse salade met tomaatjes,
                            mozzarella en verse pesto</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I thought something like this would do the trick, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.content td[colspan=2]').addClass('dus');
```

Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does work... http://jsfiddle.net/v5HK4/

Comment: Did you included **JQuery** in your project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
 $('.content td[colspan=2]').addClass('dus');
```

it works fine
just include jquery on your project without any conflicts with other tools like mootools

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TRYj/6/).this is working well..
I think you not included Jquery. It must work if everything is perfect. Use firebug to debug. I Just added this code.

```
 $('.content td[colspan=2]').addClass('dus');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the attribute name without specifying the value.

$(".content td[colspan]").addClass("dus");

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm that you are linking jquery library. also put the content class in table tag like this.

```
<table class="content">
 <td colspan="2"></td>
</table>
```

i put this code in the end of document,its working perfectly.

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.content td[colspan=2]').addClass('dus');
  </script>
```